# Can't access template data within event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to grab an ID from a collection that's included in a template:

```
this.render('new', {
  data: {
    uri: this.params.uri,
    agent: function() {
      return Agent.findOne({});
    }
  }
});
```

In the template naturally I can access the ID with:

```
{{ agent._id }}
```

But in an event:

```
Template.new.events({
  "click #create-new": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.agent); // function render.data.agent()
  }
});
```

But the data in question only seems to be accessible as a function in the event, the result of `console.log`'ing the agent:

> function render.data.agent()

Can I work with this somehow in the event? Is there another way to access this data?

Comment: Did you try calling the function (`this.agent()._id`)?

Comment: Yup that was it - tried it just after posting funnily enough! Thanks Amit - obvious when you think about it, not used to seeing functions show up in the console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got it. I have a feeling this is more of a javascript question than anything meteor specific:

```
this.agent()._id
```

Typically the one thing I hadn't tried before asking the question!